# Subview of a reused table view cell is nil for a specific row only

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, storyboard

I've been trying to resolve this issue for quite some time now and I still can't figure it out. What I have is a custom table view cell in story board. In the cell, I added 6 views and each view has an imageView subview. I set the views' tag so that I can access them later on. This table serves as a thumbnail view in my app. The problem is that, in a specific row, the last thumbnail container view no longer have the imageview as subview resulting to a crash.

Below is my code in setting up the images for the table. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
  NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ThumbnailCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    //loops through each thumbnails
    for (int i=1; i<=kNumberOfThumbnails; i++)
    {

        //get index of current thumbnail- starting value is 0
        int index=((indexPath.row *kNumberOfThumbnails)+i)-1;
        NSLog(@"index %d",index);
        //create an indexpath given the computed index and cell section
        NSIndexPath *currentIndexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:indexPath.section];
        //get number of sections
        NSArray *sections = [self.fetchedResultsController sections]; 

        NSInteger count=0;
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        //get number of objects for given section
        count = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects]; 

        NSLog(@" i: %d  number of subviews ni thumn container %d",i,thumbContainer.subviews.count);

         //get view container for thumbnails
        UIView *thumbContainer=(UIView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:i];


        UIImageView *imageView=[thumbContainer.subviews objectAtIndex:0];// this is where the app crashes.. thumbContainer no longer have a subview (for a specific row only)so it throws out an nsrangeexception

        if (index<count) 
        {

            //get file using the created indexpath
            File *imageFile=[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:currentIndexPath];

            //set image
            imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:imageFile.thumbnail];
            thumbContainer.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];

            //set tag for image view for the system to know what file is tapped
            imageView.tag=(currentIndexPath.section*kImageTagMultiplier)+currentIndexPath.row;

            //add tap gesture to thumbnail container view

            UITapGestureRecognizer *tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(resultTapped:)];
            tap.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
            [thumbContainer addGestureRecognizer:tap];   


        }
        else {
            imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@""];
            thumbContainer.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            for (UIGestureRecognizer *gest in thumbContainer.gestureRecognizers) {
                [thumbContainer removeGestureRecognizer:gest];
            }
        }


   return cell;
```

What I'm trying to do here is that I have an array of objects and each object is represented by a thumbnail image, i used a tableview to show these thumbnails.., for each row there is a fixed number of thumbnails. In the storyboard I have a cell that has 6 square views and each view has an imageview inside. The reason why i added a container view instead of just putting an imageview is that each thumbnails is tappable and i need to know what object is tapped by getting the tapgesture's view's(the container view) subview's(which is the imageview) tag.

By the way, I have put a comment  where i encounter a crash

Comment: search some standard tableView example....and follow them..

Comment: I think you need to explain more what you are trying to do. I do not understand what you try to do and what is failing.

Comment: Lot of code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` ....make an array of your `thumbnailImages` then use this `array` for `cellImage` ...

Comment: @Rajneesh071 ths is not my first time doing a table view, and this code is working except for a specific row so maybe i'm just missing out on something.. but thanks anyway..

Comment: @RickyHelgesson I've edited my question, hope i made it clearer, thanks!

Comment: @VakulSaini thank you for your suggestion, i still really dont know what's best to do, i thought it'd be better to just plot them in the storyboard and then reuse the cell than to create an array of imageviews for each row programmatically..

Comment: I am still not quite sure what you are trying to do and why you do i this way. One thing that I see is that you loop your "i" variable between 1 and count instead of the usual 0 to count-1. This often causes issues because you forget to do i-1 when you use i. Could this be the case? Also, are you sure that you get the container view and that it is empty or might it be that you actually get null from contentView viewWithTag?

Comment: @RickyHelgesson sorry if it's still not quite clear. In the storyboard, I have a cell., i've put 6 views inside the cell and each view has an imageview in it. i set the 6 view's tag from 1 to 6 (the reason why I set the initial value of var 'i' to 1). The 6 views serve as the containers so that i can access the imageviews in the cellForRowAtIndexpath method and change the imageViews' tag to the calculated index and section.

Comment: @RickyHelgesson So, why did I have to add a container view instead of just adding an imageview? The reason is that, if i set the imageView's tag, when that cell is reused the set tag is retained and the system would no longer know if the imageview is the first, second third... or sixth. To summarize, the container views are used to get the ordinal number of the thumbnails(1 -6) and the imageview's tag is to get the index of the object from the array fetched from coredata(e.g., in the 2nd row, 3rd image the index would be 9).

Comment: @RickyHelgesson About the loop with initial value of 1, i decrement 1 in getting the index, so that might not be the case. Also, I've NSLog the subviews of the container view and it appears that it's getting 1 subview except for a particular row that returns zero in the 6th container view. What's weird is that there is not a single line of code that removes any subviews in my implementation file. I guess it's a bug. By the way, thanks Ricky for your time.

Comment: I will try adding imageviews in cell.contentView programmatically just like what @VakulSaini suggested.

Comment: Well, you need to debug more... maybe you could subclass UIImageView and add logging in some places and use that to find out why the image view is never created for this particular case... or something else. Add more logging. :)

Comment: @RickyHelgesson thanks, I've tried adding them programmatically and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the new iOS 6 [`UICollectionView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) as it is designed for things like this.